# Node js Reverse Proxy PUT/POST Requests w/ Couchbase Sync Gateway

Tags: node.js, http, express, couchbase, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to build a reverse proxy in front of a Couchbase SyncGateway.  Before sending requests to the sync gateway, I'd like to send them to an authentication server for authentication, then if all is good, send the request on (unmodified from original) to the sync gateway.  The database is not staying up to date with the client modifications and I believe this is because I am not successfully proxying PUT/POST requests.  Here is the code I have:

```
var http = require('http');
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var apiProxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();
var request = require('request').defaults({json: true});

var authServer = 'http://authserverdns:5000';
var syncGateway = 'http://syncgatewaydns:4984';

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if (req.method == 'POST' || req.method == 'PUT') {
        req.body = '';

        req.addListener('data', function(chunk) {
            req.body += chunk;
        });

        req.addListener('end', function() {
            processRequest(req, res);
        });
    } else {
        processRequest(req, res);
    }

}).listen(8080);

function processRequest(req, res) {
    request(authServer, function(error, response, body) {
        if (body.authenticated) {
            console.log('authenticated !!!');
            apiProxy.web(this.req, this.res, {target: this.sg});
        } else {
            console.log('request denied !!!');
        }
   }.bind({req: req, res: res, sg: syncGateway}));
}
```

At first I was using an express server and having same issue.  As I looked into the problem, it looks like maybe there is an issue with Express and proxying PUT/POST requests.  So, I attempted to use some examples out there and this is what I've ended up with, but still not working.  Any ideas as to where I'm going wrong here?  Authenticated prints, so I know I'm getting to the point of proxying.  And the sync gateway seems to be fine with the GET requests.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ugh.  I wasn't adding the rest of the URL to the forwarding address for the Sync Gateway.  The post  [here](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/mini-hacks/blob/master/google-sign-in/README.md) helped.